# Wait for process to exit

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

How can I wait for a process to finish executing then delete it?

I start the process using `Process.Start("process.exe");`

Thank you.

Comment: How do you perform the extraction?

Comment: Check out the Parallel Task Library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx. Maybe use Task.WaitAll

Comment: I compress the files using winrar, make them automatic running in the background and start the file through C# automatically.

Comment: Can you show the code that does the compression?

Comment: I don't compress the files using C#, I simply use winrar to compress and then just start the file after the download, using winrar sfx compression.

Comment: You could have the download thread return after the download and put the extraction in the main thread.  Winrar has the option to allow the user to put the extraction in the background

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Assuming you are using something like Process.Start(), I'd rather do it in-process with a library such as this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/. It's probably easier that way.

Comment: Dear all, I have updated the question in an attempt to remedy old mistakes. Thank you all for the valuable feedback & criticism! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("update.exe", "-s"); // extract in the silent mode
proc.WaitForExit();
File.Delete("update.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great!
I'll still take a look on the libraries when I have more free time, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Method One:
Just check if the SFXs EXE-Thread is still running. The quick solution would be

```
 process.WaitForExit();
```

Method Two: 
Use Rar und decompress the SFX and check whether the file is still accessed (blocked) periodically.

But I would *strictly* recommend to use a rar library. So you do not depend on a specific installation of rar (which may even differ depending on the OS)

The following library seems to fit your needs: http://nunrar.codeplex.com/

The library should not care if it is a "real" rar or an sfx file